# How to remove black square in the proof?

Tags: math-mode, margins, templates

I am using the template of a journal. It requires removing black square at the end of proof. I tried it but it was not successful. Could you help me to remove it

The link is https://www.sharelatex.com/project/57f24aca9c3e08834f150c41

A short code is

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{el-author}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{}


\begin{document}

\title{Instructions and example template for \LaTeX{} submissions to \emph{Electronics Letters}}

\author{J. Smith and A. N. Other}

\abstract{This document describes how to use the el-author.cls file and how to format your \LaTeX submissions
correctly}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

This is Lemma and prof
\begin{lemma} \label{lemma1}
This is lemma
\end{lemma}
\begin{proof}
This is proof
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

Updated: I found that only has one solution for that

```
\usepackage{amsthm,amssymb}
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{myproof}[1][\proofname]{\par
    \normalfont \topsep6\p@\@plus6\p@\relax
    \trivlist
    \item[\hskip\labelsep
    \itshape
    #1\@addpunct{.}]\ignorespaces
}{%
\endtrivlist\@endpefalse
}
\makeatother
```

Then changes the `proof` to `myproof`

Comment: If you're using a template of a journal, which provides a black square at the end of a proof, you should either keep that (as that is what templates are for) or consider if it's actually a proof you want to typeset.

Comment: But the editor requires the delete them. I am not sure about it

Comment: Are they really requiring you to use a class file that has not beed updated since 2000? They class explicitly sets a black square at the end of proofs. This is a choice of the journal and as @thewaywewalk mentions, this is **their** choice, and you will be wasting your time trying to remove it.

Comment: @user8430 are you sure then that this template and class **is** the one required for this journal. You should not need to hack a class provided as a termplate for a journal

Comment: I don't know why they require it. The editor requires to my paper that "Please delete the black squares from the margin of your text."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class redefines `proof` to use `$\blacksquare$` instead of `\qedsymbol`, so your redefinition of the latter is useless.

If you cannot edit the class file, you can do as follows

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{el-author}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\AtBeginDocument{\xpatchcmd\proof{$\blacksquare$}{\qedsymbol}{}{}}
%\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{$\blacksquare$} % as the class wants
\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{}


\begin{document}
\title{Instructions and example template for \LaTeX{} submissions to \emph{Electronics Letters}}

\author{J. Smith and A. N. Other}

\abstract{This document describes how to use the el-author.cls file and 
how to format your \LaTeX submissions correctly}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

This is Lemma and prof
\begin{lemma} \label{lemma1}
This is lemma
\end{lemma}
\begin{proof}
This is proof
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: i haven't looked at (or for) the document class, but if the commented-out line in your code is from that file, why is it even necessary to perform the patch?  why not just renew `\qedsymbol` out of visible existence?

Comment: @barbarabeeton The class redefines `proof` to explicitly use `$\blacksquare$` instead of simply doing `\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{\ensuremath{\blacksquare}}`, which would be the right thing to do. So I added a commented line in case the OP needs to switch back to the expected output.

Answer (score 1):

Putting the following *after* begin{document} (not in the preamble) seems working. I have no idea why.

```
....
\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{proof}[1][\proofname]{\par
  %\pushQED{\hfill\blacksquare}%
  \normalfont \topsep6\p@\@plus6\p@\relax
  \trivlist
  \item[\hskip\labelsep
        \itshape
    #1\@addpunct{:}]\ignorespaces
}{%
  %\popQED
  \endtrivlist\@endpefalse
}
\makeatother

\begin{theorem}...
```

I copied the above from the class file and commented out \pushQED and \popQED.

Comment: Let see my updates. Only it can work, instead of your solution

Comment: Only if you are happy with changing all the proof environments to myproof.